# Como converter uma String para Date em Swift

Tags: swift, data, conversão-de-tipo

eu recebo a data da seguinte forma 2016-08-14T20:38:27.031-03:00 como string, gostaria de passar para data no padrão dd/MM/yyyy, já procurei na net algumas soluções porém não foram úteis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para este formato de data `2016-08-14T20:38:27.031-03:00` iso8601, voce precisa usar o seguinte formato com milésimo de segundos `SSS` e `XXX`  para time zone (`-03:00` ou `Z`):

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

**Xcode 8 Beta 6 • Swift 3**

```
extension Date {
    struct Formatter {
        static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var iso8601: String { return Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self) }
}

extension String {
    var dateFromISO8601: Date? {
        return Date.Formatter.iso8601.date(from: self)
    }
}

Date() // "Aug 18, 2016, 8:09 PM"
let dateString = Date().iso8601  // "2016-08-18T23:09:59.830Z"
print(dateString) //  "2016-08-18T23:09:59.830Z\n"

if let dateFromString = dateString.dateFromISO8601 {
    print(dateFromString)   // "2016-08-18 23:09:59 +0000\n"
    print(dateFromString.iso8601)  // "2016-08-18T23:09:59.830Z"
}
```

---

**Xcode 7.3.1 • Swift 2.2.1**

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Formatter {
        static let iso8601: NSDateFormatter = {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
            formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var iso8601: String { return Formatter.iso8601.stringFromDate(self) }
}

extension String {
    var dateFromISO8601: NSDate? {
        return NSDate.Formatter.iso8601.dateFromString(self)
    }
}

NSDate() // "Aug 19, 2016, 1:49 AM"
let dateString = NSDate().iso8601  // "2016-08-19T04:49:35.792Z"
print(dateString) //  "2016-08-19T04:49:35.792Z\n"

if let dateFromString = dateString.dateFromISO8601 {
    print(dateFromString)   // "2016-08-19 04:49:35 +0000\n"
    print(dateFromString.iso8601)  // "2016-08-19T04:49:35.792Z\n"
}
```

Uma vez que voce tem a sua data no formato NSDate voce deve usar o NSDateFormatter para formatar a data para o usuário. Voce nao deve especificar o formato e sim o estilo da data `dateStyle` (short, medium, long ou full). Desta forma a data sera formatada de acordo com as preferencias de região do usuário. Segue o link da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865) do site em Ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Se precisar de uma tabela pra referencia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a classe [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/%22NSDateFormatter%22) para fazer esta conversão.

Exemplo:

```
let dateString = "2016-08-14T20:38:27.031-03:00"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)) // Saída: 14/08/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

De forma simplificada, você deve fazer exatamente isso:

```
let dateString = "2016-09-16T21:09:22.031-03:00" // Data de entrada
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() //Instância do date Formatter
//Aqui você DEVE indicar qual formato é sua data de entrada. 
//Se caso não for do formato que você colocou, ocorrerá uma exception!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZZZZZ" 
//Aqui você está Convertendo sua date String para uma data válida
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
//Aqui você está mudando o formato que você quer retornar
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
//Aqui você está convertendo a data que você transformou para date em String no formato "novo" que você modificou acima.
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)) // Saída: 16/09/2016
```